# Null character not showing up in cout

Tags: c++

In this block of code I show you that I know a string array should end with a NULL character.

```
#include <iostream>    
void main(){
    char c[4] = { 'a','b','c', '\0'}; //OR char c[4]={'a', 'b', 'c'}
    std::cout << c << "d";
}
```

Output is: "abcd"
-- What I was expecting: "abc d"

And in this one, I was taught that strings end with a NULL character in cpp.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
void main() {
    string c = "abc";
    std::cout << c << "d";
}
```

Output is: "abcd"
-- What I was expecting: "abc d"

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: The null marks the end of the string and is not printed. It's only reason to exist is to tell readers where to stop reading.

Comment: @JakeFreeman yes it is, try char c = 0; std::cout << "Hello" << c  << "World";

Comment: @Shayan that prints HelloWorld..... Jake Freeman is correct Null is not a space.

Comment: @Shayan You don't see the zeroes that terminate `"Hello"` and `"World"`, do you? IIRC, what happens when you print an actual `NUL` is terminal-specific.

Comment: @user4581301 Interesting, I tried char c[4] = { 'a','b','c', '\0' }; std::cout << c[4] << "d"; and it printed ╠d .

Comment: `c[4]` is not in the bounds of  the array. You have invoked undefined behaviour and will get whatever you get.

Comment: @molbdnilo I don't get what you mean, because char c = 0 converts the ASCII code 00 to whatever and puts it in c and NULL is probably space idk, can you elaborate?

Comment: in ASCII space is 32. 32 != 0.

Comment: @user4581301 Oh yes, my bad I meant to do c[3] not c[4] so yeah I did c[3] and it printed " d". see NULL is space after all :)

Comment: Nope. What happened is your terminal software didn't know what to do with a null, so it printed a space. Other common solutions are a box or a question mark.

Comment: @Shayan "Null" means "none", "nothing", "invalid". It's not a printable character. The space character is *something*, and is encoded as 32 in ASCII. What the terminal does with non-printable characters is terminal-specific.

Comment: @molbdnilo If I do char c[3]={'a', 'b'} then c[2] and c[3] are both NULL? or which one is going to be NULL?

Comment: @Shayan If you have too few initializers for an array of primitives, the unspecified elements are initialized to zero, but in your case `c[3]` doesn't even exist.

Comment: @molbdnilo Oh, I made that mistake again, I should have done c[4] so if I do c[4]= {'a', 'b'} then c[2] is going to be 0 and c[3] is going to be NULL correct?

Comment: @Shayan: both `c[2]` and `c[3]` will be `'\0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Strings" when represented as a sequence of characters (like in `char c[4]`) are terminated by a special character, which you call the NULL character (actually `'\0'`). As datatypes like `char c[4]` do not maintain any additional information on the length of the string, this is the convention followed by functions interpreting an object of type `char[]` as a string to "know where to stop". `cout` interprets an input of type `char[]` as such a string and will stop *before*  outputting this character, i.e. it will not print a space or something else. So character `'c'` will be the last one to print, and whenn printing a `"d"` right afterwards no speparator will show up in between.

Note that `char c[4]={'a', 'b', 'c'}` will work, too, though the reason is a little bit subtle. Initializing a sequence of characters this way will - even if you pass less characters in the brace initializer than you declare as the size of the array - will implicitly fill up the array with  `'\0'`. So it works. `char c[4]={'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}`, in contrast, will yield undefined behaviour once you  use this  character  sequence in a function that expects a `'\0'`-terminated string.

Comment: If I do char c[5]={'a', 'b', 'c'} where is the NULL character going to be? in c[3] or in c[4]?

Comment: In both, `c[3]` and `c[4]`; the complete array will be filled up with it. For string functions, the first occurrence counts,  i.e. that in `c[3]`.

Comment: Going to add this for anybody else who might be interested: `char c[4] = {'a','b','c','d'};` does not return an error but `char c[4] = "abcd";` returns an error because it's too large, `char c[4] = "abc"` is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your post is that the `'\0'` is not a space and thus your outputs are correct.

Hope this helps.