# How to print Null character as a character in CPP?

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
    
    string s = "Hello\t\0world";
    string k = "";
    
    for(auto i =0; i<s.length();i++){
        switch(s[i]){
            case '\t':
                k = k + "\\t";
                break;
            case '\0':
                k = k + "\\0";
                break;
            default:
                k = k + s[i];
        }
    }
    cout<<k;
    return 0;
}
```

After null character string is ending and not able to get full solution.

Output should be: `Hello\t\0world`

Comment: [Null character not showing up in cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761686/null-character-not-showing-up-in-cout)

Comment: @Jason the null isn't printed even if it made it into the string in the first place, it's replaced with `\\0`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the initialization of `s`. The initialization will stop at the null-character embedded in the string.

You need to do the initialization in three steps:

```
string s = "Hello\t";  // First part of string
s += '\0';  // Add the terminator character
s += "world";  // Add the second part of the string
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could just tell the `string` constructor what the full length is: `string s("Hello\t\0world", 12);`

Comment: *"You need to do the initialization in three steps:..."* Technically the last 2 steps that uses `+=` are not initialization.